# Dúvida sobre Progress 4GL

Tags: revisão-de-código

Eu sou novo no desenvolvimento progress, e tô com dificuldade para entender o que faz esse trecho de código:

```
define variable cRunFile as character no-undo initial "gpldnfbr.p".

        {us/gp/gpmnp02.i cRunFile 10 """(input p_oid_lgdd_det,
                                         output p_exclude_app)"""}
```

Pedi uma ajudinha aqui e o meu supervisor me falou que é um hook que chama outro programa, mas ainda fiquei na dúvida, não ficou muito claro, sabe.

Answer (score -1):

Trabalho com progress 4gl a uns 9 anos, rs... vou tentar explicar o que entendo...

- `define variable` - Definição padrão de variável
- `cRunFile` - Nome da Variável
- `as character` - Tipo da Variável
- `no-undo` - Não precisa armazenar para possível desfazimento
- `initial "gpldnfbr.p"` - Valor inicial da variável
- `{us/gp/gpmnp02.i` - Include arquivo como se o conteúdo estivesse dentro do programa, apenas uma maneira de deixar o código mais limpo
- `cRunFile` - Chamando o `"gpldnfbr.p"` declarado na variável
- `10` - Creio que seja o valor de um parâmetro
- `"""(input p_oid_lgdd_det,` - Parâmetro de entrada
- `output p_exclude_app)"""}` - Parâmetro de saida

Espero ter contribuído :)

Comment: Ola @Luciano, fiz uma edição na sua resposta, veja se ela representa sua intenção, caso não você pode [reverte-la aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/409860/revisions). =D

Comment: Obrigado @IcaroMartins, enquanto editava estava com as quebras de linha, quando postei juntou tudo...preciso aprender a mexer mais aqui...